# cannot access crontab after changing uid

Tags: cron, uid

I recently changed the uid of my linux account (the reason for this change lies in the need to have a precise uid to access files on a mounted drive). Since then, I cannot access my crontab. After typing:

```
crontab -e
```

I get the error message:

```
crontabs/my_login/: fopen: Permission denied
```

I investigated the permissions associated to the file /usr/bin/crontab, it is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root my_login 35984 Feb  9  2013
```

However, if I look at the id of my_login, I get:

```
uid=11375(my_login) gid=1000(my_login) groups=1000(my_login),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),107(lpadmin),110(sambashare)
```

I can see something seems wrong with the gid but I am not sure what to do from this point...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your permissions are incorrect for the `crontab` file.  What it should be is like the following:

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 35984 Feb  9  2013 /usr/bin/crontab
```

To set your `crontab` to the above permissions, first change the ownership:

```
sudo chown root:crontab /usr/bin/crontab
```

Then set the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 2755 /usr/bin/crontab
```

That should set your `crontab` to the correct permissions to run.

**EDIT:**

Also, take a look at the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` folder, you should see something similar to the following:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -al /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
total 16
drwx-wx--T 2 root     crontab 4096 Dec 17 22:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root    4096 Dec  1 07:24 ..
-rw------- 1 root     crontab 1185 Dec 17 22:08 root
-rw------- 1 terrance crontab 1130 Dec 17 21:47 terrance
```

Pay attention to your username.  If it doesn't have the proper ownership, change it by typing in the following:

```
sudo chown username:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username
```

And if permissions need to be set on that file:

```
sudo chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it did not fix my problem. I now have the permissions you mention :     {-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 35984 Feb  9  2013 crontab*}    but I still get "permssion denied" after typing "crontab -e"

Comment: @Alain Edited my answer for the spool file permissions as well.  Hope I can help you get this fixed.  =)

Comment: @Alain Not a problem.  Glad it is working for you!  =)

Comment: I also had to run: sudo chmod g+w /var/spool/cron/crontabs; sudo chown root:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs - for some reason on DietPi /var/spool/cron/crontabs was owned by root:root.